Error Code 137 while using Elasticache Redis with ECS Fargate
I am running containers on ECS Fargate and everything is working as expected but there is one issue. When I have this redis code running in my server side, the server container is failing to reach a steady state and failing.
And when I expand the api container its showing Error Code 137
const REDIS_ENDPOINT = process.env.REDIS_ENDPOINT;

const pubClient = createClient({
  url: REDIS_ENDPOINT,
});

const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

await Promise.all([pubClient.connect(), subClient.connect()]);

Plus there are no logs given by the server container in my cloudwatch. All other containers are working as expected such as client, nginx, mongo and redis.

After doing some more research, I read that its due to the memory and I tried increasing that to 15 gb in my ECS task definition which is more that enough (Just for checking). I am sure its not this issue since everything is working with 6 gb when I don't have the above mentioned code.

My elasticache redis endpoint is also in the correct format redis://mycompany-534sdf.serverless.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379

I have port 6379 open in my security group

Everything is working as expected locally when I am using docker compose


Really need some help here. I am pulling my hair out as I am typing this.

I don't see how the amount of memory would be causing this issue. If it was you should be seeing out-of-memory errors in the logs. I would try increasing the log level of your application, or adding some print or log statements to your code so you can debug this further. It really does sounds like an issue with the ElastiCache security group though, can you post the acutal inbound rule(s) you have defined in the security group?

I would love to see the log statements but I am getting "No logs" for my server container.
Security group for ALB: port range - 3000, 80, 6379, 5000, 443 | Security group for Elasticache - port range 0 - 65535
I think its something with the elasticache redis connectivity with ECS container

What IP addresses or security groups are you allowing in the ElastiCache security group inbound rule?

As for logs, if other containers in the same ECS task are showing logs, then this container simply isn't printing any logs, and you need to add some log statements.

ElastiCache security group only has All TCP as inbound rule

I am getting the logs properly when I don't have the above mentioned code. I have "Use log collection" enabled in my task definition for all my containers.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

All TCP describes the ports. That's another way of saying "port range 0 - 65535`. A security group rule has two settings, the port numbers, and the allowed IP addresses (or security groups). You keep telling me the port numbers, but it is the allowed IP addresses that would be causing this issue.

It is open for all Ip address 0.0.0.0/0.

If adding that code causes logs to stop working, then the new code appears to be hanging forever. If you have any logs before this code you should still see it. I would start by logging the value of REDIS_ENDPOINT before attempting to connect to ElastiCache, in order to verify that environment variable has the value you think it does.

thanks Mark I will give this a shot :)

Can we move it to chat if you don't mind? The comments are getting long.

It looks like some sort of network connection issue. I don't know how to help you further given the amount of detail you have provided. The ElastiCache cluster is in the same VPC as the ECS cluster, correct? I don't get notifications when you post messages here in chat, which is why I avoid using chat on this site because I don't want to have to keep a bunch of chat windows open all day just to see if somebody has sent me a message.

Yes the problem is with the connectivity, the code is stopping at await Promise.all. Everything is in the same VPC also.

I solved it. I don't know suddenly it started working. Idk what I did. Thanks for helping me @MarkB

I was using Elasticache Redis serverless and found out that it does not support pub sub capability.
You have to create your own cluster and everything will work fine.
